# How to build a model attribute as string using checkboxes (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a welding_certificate model with bw_positions attribute.
I want to be able to pick welding positions through checkboxes

```
<%= check_box_tag "bw_positions[]", "PA" %>PA
<%= check_box_tag "bw_positions[]", "PB" %>PB
<%= check_box_tag "bw_positions[]", "PC" %>PC
```

and store them as string for example "PA, PC" or "PA, PB, PC".

The parameters sent to the controller are looking allright:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"NSQ9FlN3hqaLbgCkVkDKHgsLOdTp20hkDpXtwqh7ZgiWOB04H0qg6s9_mpyTk03SdFGHRH4paVkA7ZiXvaoCNQ", "welding_certificate"=>{"code"=>"PN EN ISO 9606-1", "number"=>"1234", "material_group"=>"FM5, FM4", "methods"=>"141", "bw"=>"1", "fw"=>"0", "diameter_min"=>"1", "diameter_maks"=>"2", "thk_min"=>"1", "thk_maks"=>"2", "valid_since"=>"2021-04-06", "valid_until"=>"2021-04-28"}, **"bw_positions"=>["PA", "PB"]**, "commit"=>"Zatwierdź", "controller"=>"welding_certificates", "action"=>"update", "welder_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

But the data does is not saved to the database...

Update 07.04.2021
My strong params function looks like this

```
def welding_certificate_params
    params.require(:welding_certificate).permit(:number, :valid_since, :valid_until, :material_group, :diameter_min,                               :diameter_maks, :thk_min, :thk_maks, :methods,                                                :code, :bw, :fw, :body_id, :bw_positions, :fw_positions,                                                :prolongation_date)    
end
```

I have changed check boxes so they look like this

```
<%= check_box_tag "welding_certificate[bw_positions]", "PA" %>PA
<%= check_box_tag "welding_certificate[bw_positions]", "PB" %>PB
```

and this way the data is sent to database but only as one of the array's item not whole string. If I change to

```
<%= check_box_tag "welding_certificate[bw_positions][]", "PA" %>PA
<%= check_box_tag "welding_certificate[bw_positions][]", "PB" %>PB
```

i am getting

```
Unpermitted parameter: :bw_positions
```

in logger...

Comment: bw_positions is nested in welding_certificate. You would need `params[:welding_certificate][:bw_positions]`.

Comment: Thank You but changing from ```<%= check_box_tag "bw_positions[]", "PA" %>PA``` to ```<%= check_box_tag "welding_certificates[bw_positions][]", "PA" %>PA``` didn't change the situation... I tried ```<%= check_box_tag "welding_certificate[bw_positions][]", "PA" %>PA``` welding_certificate - singular but this caused and error in the console "Unpermitted parameter: :bw_positions"

Comment: You need to show us more details, like your model.

Comment: No in the controller. In your original post you were trying to build an array with `params[:bw_positions]` it would be `params[:welding_certificate][:bw_positions]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the very last part of the parameters object in your post may be part of the problem: `permitted: false` means the params haven't been filtered through strong parameters.

I'm guessing there is a method in your controller named `welding_certificate_params` that you need to change to something like the following:

```
def welding_certificate_params
  params.require(:welding_certificate).permit( [whatever other params you have], :bw_positions => [] )
end
```

See [the api on strong parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) for more info

Answer (score 0):

[sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12498105/sam) - thank You

**My controller**

```
  def welding_certificate_params

    if params[:bw_positions]
      params[:welding_certificate][:bw_positions] = Array(params[:bw_positions]).join(", ")
    end

    params.require(:welding_certificate).permit(:number, :valid_since, :valid_until, :material_group, :diameter_min,
                                                :diameter_maks, :thk_min, :thk_maks, :methods, 
                                                :code, :bw, :fw, :body_id, :bw_positions, :fw_positions,
                                                :prolongation_date)

    
  end
```

**My View**

```
<% positions = ["PA", "PB", "PC", "PD"] %>


            
            <% positions.each do |position| %>

                <%= check_box_tag "bw_positions[]", position %><%=" #{position}"%>

            <%end%>
```

It works finally :D